# console.time doesn't support QLoggingCategory?

Tags: javascript, qt, qt5, qtquick2, console.log

I'm trying to reduce the amount of log output in my QtQuick application by creating many logging categories [like documented here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-loggingcategory.html).

> A logging category can be passed to console.log() and friends as the first argument. If supplied to to the logger the LoggingCategory's name will be used as Logging Category otherwise the default logging category will be used.

Now I'm trying to do that with `console.time()` and `console.timeEnd()` ([documented here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-debugging.html#timer)).

I get some errors in the log output:

```
qrc:/main.qml:16: Error: console.time(): Invalid arguments
```

**How can I use logging categories for `console.time()`?**

Example code:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    LoggingCategory {
        id: category
        name: "some.not.so.important.stuff"
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.time(category, 'start');
        console.timeEnd(category, 'start');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where documentation says

> A logging category can be passed to console.[log()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-debugging.html#log) and friends as the
>   first argument

it refers to console.log, console.debug, console.info, console.warn and console.error, which are all meant to just print messages.

The other console features (Assert, Timer, etc.) do not support logging categories.

Comment: that is sad... i didn't understand the term "and friends". is there any workaround using if's?